# Review best practice

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I've been running into quite a few reviews lately that I've skipped because I've been unsure what the appropriate response is, so I'd like to check with the community.

Specifically:

1. OK-looking edits on a question that should be closed (or one of its answers).
2. Beneficial tag-only edits when the question body also needs improvement.
3. Answers which are really a comment on the question/another answer, but which due to length and/or code content wouldn't really work in the comment format.
4. "Low Quality" flags on answers which appear to be a valid attempt at answering the question (i.e. have code and some sort of explanation). I get the impression that these are raised by people due to technical issues (errors/bad security) in the answer. Am I right in thinking the correct way to deal with this is a comment on the answer, so I should respond "Looks OK" in the LQP queue?

Comment: Are you asking if it is ok to skip the review in those cases?

Comment: especially point 4 speaks to me from the heart, thank you for bringing it up.

Comment: Why would you skip in case 1 if you think that the edit is ok?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Because the edit isn't helpful if the question is just going to end up being deleted regardless.  Arraigning deck chairs on the Titanic, etc.

Comment: @Servy Regardless of the action the outcome will be mostly the same: 1. effort for all reviewers and 2. the +2 rep gain that will be reversed if this is approved but later deleted.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The difference is that the editor will think they did the right thing, even though they didn't.  And the initial feedback of the approval/rejection has been demonstrated to be far more influential than any subsequent deletions.

Comment: @Servy But why do you think that it is bad to propose an edit to bad posts? If the post is indeed not deleted, then the edit *does* add something useful, because it was approved.

Comment: @ArtjomB. If the edit is turning the post into something worth not deleting, then it's a great edit.  If the post is still worth deleting even after the edit, then it's not adding value.  It's the value *after* the edit that matters, not before the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Approve of them if they are indeed OK, but you can leave a polite comment to the editor saying: "This question lacks x so there is no need for you to put effort into editing it. A better action is to close/flag". Then close/flag the question yourself and down vote if needed.
2. If the tag adds nothing of value, pick the "Reject and edit" option. If the tag is needed, then preferably pick the "improve edit" button. Or if you are too lazy to fix the post, just approve.
3. Flag as "not an answer". The limited length and poor code formatting of comments is no excuse to post comments as answers (the comment fields could do with some improvement here). Same goes for users who don't have enough rep to comment and therefore posts an answer instead.
4. If the answer looks ok and attempts to answer the question, then select "looks ok". If an answer is horribly incorrect but otherwise on-topic, it should be down voted but not flagged. Most often you shouldn't need to know the technical stuff when doing reviews.

   There does exist a rare case where the answer looks fine, but it is completely non-related to the question and therefore needs to be deleted. For example, OP asks about a C++ linked list problem, and the answer just dumps some random C++ code not in the slightest related. When this happens, it is often because the one who wrote the answer misunderstood the question completely.

   In such cases, whoever flagged the post needs to leave a comment behind about this, so that the reviewer who lacks the technical knowledge of the topic can press skip and leave the review to someone who does have the knowledge. But this is such a rare thing, that I would say it is no big deal if you pick "looks ok". There is always a slight bit of "collateral damage" during reviews, for these odd special cases. Given enough down votes, the answer will lose creditability anyhow, despite the post slipping past the review.

Answer (score 0):

1. If an edit is correct, approve it, the user might not be able to judge if the Q/A has to be closed
2. A Tag edit is a relevant edit, the user might not be able to improve more due to lacking engslisch knowledge
3. If it's really a comment and not an attempt to answer in any way vote for deleting it.
4. Many answers in the LQP should never be seen there. Any answer, except link only answers, trying to answer, regardless of the quality, is a valid answer and should be handled with "Looks OK". 
   You might add an comment and/or downvoted if necessary. You might step into the task to see if it's an answer or an comment/answer to an existing answer, not to the question itself.