# Should there be a help section on "How to be a good reviewer according to Stack Overflow"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

My reviews are sometimes rejected by to the Stack Overflow review-system and I get redirected to a screen that says I should pay more attention and that luckily they already took care of the apparently bad post. However I can't find any sufficiently detailed guidelines for reviewing.

There is clearly a specific way in which Stack Overflow would like us to review questions. This is not always clear to many people (as evidenced by the many posts asking about specific review-cases). I think a section in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for reviewers would be valuable.

I could find some individual posts closely or more indirectly related to the individual review buttons: [Unsalvageable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292251/when-is-a-question-deemed-unsalvagable)
[Should be improved and Unsalaveable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278747/3972558) when to mark something [Looks ok](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266428/low-quality-review-queue-meaning-of-looks-ok).
A not so similar post about how to be a good reviewer is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275962/review-best-practice/275967#275967), but is too broad and does not get to the real problem, that is "how is it possible in the first place that people are often left behind with questions about how to review a post?"

If the system rejects a review I should at least be able to find out why; only then I can really prevent this from happening again.

Comment: I think it would be great if something pops out at the face of first time reviewer in a queue and instruct them on how to review. Going to meta (which I believe contains the information you need to know to some degree) is a hassle.

Comment: loosely related feature request where users could practice reviewing and get feedback on their choice: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly. If such a system was in place, there is no reason it couldn't be used as a tutorial for review decisions as well as educating new users.

Comment: One user actually started writing a [meta-tag:faq-proposed] post for [guidelines for the first-post and late-answer queues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts).

Comment: The Mother Meta has [a fair amount of general guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing).