# Should there be clearer, easier-to-find general documentation for how to review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I think it would be great if there was a link in each review queue page to some documentation about how the various options for that specific review type are intended to be used.

My current method for trying to review correctly:

1. Go to a review queue
2. Skip items I don't know enough about to review
3. Review items where the review choice seems obvious to me
4. When the review choice does not seem obvious to me...

   - Go to Meta and search for the specific non-obviousness I think I've encountered
   - If I can't find a Meta Q&A that clears up my confusion, ask a question.
   - If that doesn't work, skip the review item (by that time the review is probably already completed anyway.)

All my previous searching for various "how to review" topics has been too specific for me to have found "[What are the guidelines for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)" until I was looking for the answer to this more general question.

I don't know if everyone goes through a similar process, but as a relatively new reviewer, I would have liked to read some more "official" guidance on how Stack Overflow intended a certain review queue to be used before I started trying to use it, rather than just jumping in and searching for answers when I got confused about something.

I understand that there would still be plenty of cases too specific to be covered by that documentation that would still need meta questions.

I also get that a lot of people don't read instructions anyway, but I think there are also plenty of people who *would* read them if they were right there and they didn't have to go looking for them.

I think the "What are the guidelines for reviewing" post is really helpful, I just wish it could be easier to get to that information directly from the review page.

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292350/should-there-be-a-help-section-on-how-to-be-a-good-reviewer-according-to-stacko) that proposes adding something to the help pages, which seems fine, but I think it would be even better if there was an even more direct route; maybe something like

[image: new toolbar button]

Comment: Yes. There needs to be more documentation on everything. Half of SO's policies are spread out over various meta.SO and meta.SE posts, the other half only lives in the heads of users. This goes from _"Which close reason to pick"_, _"Which kind of edits are appropriate"_ and _"Which flag to use"_ to the issue you're describing here, and it differs between who happens to read and bother to answer the relevant meta posts. Just as on SO, asking the same question on meta on different days can yield surprisingly different results.

Comment: I had this exact question in mind for the last few days since I failed a review audit for a non obvious reason. I found the same link you did after some Googling, but I agree it should be more obvious. Perhaps the first time you enter a review queue (which should be known as you won't have the [tag:custodian] badge) the first few (5?) reviews are a "tutorial" of sorts showing good and bad reviews and highlighting common mistakes.

Comment: I asked if there was a [FAQ for Triage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-triage) around the time I got access to it. I agree that a direct link to info on how to review would be helpful. If anything, the people reviewing would probably be **more** likely to read instructions since they're basically volunteering for extra moderation work. Aside from robo-reviewers, they wouldn't be doing it if they didn't care to get it right.

Comment: My sentiments, exactly.

Comment: Problem is, in a consensus-driven community, who should write it?

Comment: @GertArnold That's a good point. I suppose, considering that, the community should write it. "What are the guidelines for reviewing" is all community wiki; do you think that's sufficiently written by the community? I'm still not 100% clear on how community wiki works.